# Print user's IP address in WSO2 identity servers log

Tags: wso2, saml, spring-saml, wso2-identity-server

My application is integrated with WSO2 Identity Server 5.3 with SAML 2.0 using spring security saml extention, and working fine. Now I need to print user's IP address in the logs of WSO2 Identity server. Any idea how to achieve this?

Note: I have created custom authenticator and custom user store to customize the authentication process.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks.. I will keep in mind.

Comment: Doesn't this get printed in the http access logs?
Do you want it to get printed in the wso2carbon.log ?

Comment: http://sparkletechthoughts.blogspot.com/2013/07/configure-access-logging-in-wso2.html

Comment: Yes!!! I want to print this in WSO2Carbon.log. Also I need to capture the same inside custom authenticator, so that I can send this IP to an external SOAP service to save in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by extending BasicAuthenticator. This class has a method with parameter HttpServletRequest. Rest was easy, I got the IP and other client information and called a web services to save the same in DB.

**protected void processAuthenticationResponse(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                 HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationContext context)**